# UIView.animateWithDuration in viewDidAppear happens instantly

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, viewdidappear, animatewithduration

Easy to reproduce:

- create a new app
- copy this code to your view controller that is being launched at start

  ```
  class ViewController: UIViewController {

      override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
          UIView.animateWithDuration(5,
              delay: 5,
              options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut,
              animations: {

              }, completion: { finished in
                  print("finished")
              }
          )
      }

  }
  ```

"finished" is logged instantly when I'd expect it to be logged 10 seconds after launch (5 from the animation duration + 5 from the delay).

How do I fix this?

The original problem I'm trying to solve is to `presentViewController` (with `animated: false`) before `viewDidAppear`, so that I can show the user a `LoginViewController`before the view for the controller in the back appears.
But turns out that I can't call `presentViewController` in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`.

So my workaround would be to set the `LoginViewController`'s view's alpha to 0 and animate it to 1 (I know, it is a different effect, but it's better than calling `presentViewController` in `viewDidAppear` causing have the main controller to show and after a millisecond `(not literally)` have the `LoginViewController`'s view appear).